# Accessing partial results of a FileReader in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, coffeescript, filereader, fileapi

I want to use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) in my web application to *partially* load a CSV file into the browser. However, I am not able to access *partial results* in Firefox 27.

My application requires only the first 100k bytes of the CSV file to populate a data preview. Therefore, I setup, start, and then [`abort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.abort) the reader after a certain amount of data has been loaded.

Here is an example that works fine in Chrome 35:

```
  warn = (a...) -> console.warn a...
  readFile = (file,cb,limit=1e5) ->
    warn "start reading file..."
    fr = new FileReader
    result = null
    done = -> cb null,result[..limit]
    copy = (e) ->
      if e.target.result? then result = e.target.result; warn "copied #{result.length} bytes"
      else warn "result is empty"
    fr.onloadstart = (e) -> warn "Reading #{file.name} locally..."
    fr.onloadend   = (e) -> warn "Reading finished (end)";   copy(e); done()
    fr.onabort     = (e) -> warn "Reading finished (abort)"; copy(e)
    fr.onload      = (e) -> warn "Reading finished (load)";  copy(e)
    fr.onprogress  = (e) ->
      warn "progress.."; copy(e)
      if e.loaded > limit
        warn "Read #{e.loaded} bytes of CSV file for data preview. Aborting FileReader."
        fr.abort(); fr.onprogress = null
    fr.readAsText file
```

However, the code does not work in Firefox; all copied results are empty when aborting the reader. None of the events `e` carries an `e.target.result` other than `null`, even if the `progress` event indicates that some data has been read, as `e.loaded` is set correctly and thus the `abort()` is also triggered as expected.

Obviously Chrome and Firefox seem to implement the File API differently, i.e., handle the `abort()` differently. In Firefox you always have to fully load a file to get any result. For me this is not suitable, since my CSV files have 200MB or more bytes of data, leaving me with a frozen browser when having to load the data completely.

*PS: I only care for Chrome and FF. IE and mobile are out of scope for this project*

**EDIT:** Here is the final solution that works nicely in Chrome and Firefox:

```
  readFile = (file,cb,limit=1e4) ->
    warn "start reading file..."
    fr = new FileReader
    done = (e) ->
      warn "Read #{e.loaded} of #{file.size} bytes of CSV file for data preview"
      cb null,fr.result
    fr.onloadstart = (e) -> warn "Reading #{file.name} locally..."
    fr.onload      = (e) -> warn "Reading finished (load)"; done(e)
    fr.readAsText file.slice 0,limit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome violates the current spec draft which states for `abort()`:

> If readyState = LOADING set readyState to DONE and **result to null**.
>   <sup>([source](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#abort), emphasis mine)</sup>

Now, you can argue whether this is a good or bad thing to do...

The best way to read only part of the file is to [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice) the File/Blob object before passing it to the reader, telling the browser to read only part of the file in the first place:

```
fr.readAsText(file.slice(0, limit));
```

Of course, you might have to deal with issues when processing multi-byte encodings such as UTF-8... But you'd have to deal with that anyway, even with your Chrome-only `abort()` stuff.

Comment: Thanks! `Blob.slice` did the trick. I even do not need to manually abort file loading that way.