# Random access to a file in browser File API

Tags: javascript, browser, fileapi

I can use the [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) to read the whole file with       `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {
  const fileList = this.files;
  if (fileList.length != 1) return
  const file = fileList[0];

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
    ...
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

How do I perform a *random* read on a file in the browser?  e.g. `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file, offset, length);`

The data I need is at the end of the file, so aborting after a partial read is not a solution.

I only want to read a small part of a multi-GB file - reading it all to RAM is not an option.  How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing partial results of a FileReader in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809960/accessing-partial-results-of-a-filereader-in-firefox)

Comment: You could maybe listen for load or progress events and `abort` the file reader if you read enough data?!

Comment: Maybe `file.stream()` could be of help as well letting you stream the incoming data and maybe properly stop consuming the stream if needed.

Comment: @Ouroborus The data I need is on the end of the file, and I then need to seek back a variable amount (depending on what was read from the end).

Comment: @luk2302 `file.stream()` appears to be an API for downloading from the server, not for reading from a local file.  Am I mistaken?  If so are there any docs?  (It would be OK, but not great, to read the whole file.  What I can't do is read the whole file into memory as it's a multi-GB file.)

Comment: The key is that [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) inherits from [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and `Blob` supports [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice). Grab the `File` out of the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). Use `.slice()` to read the chunks you need.

Comment: @Ouroborus Would you like to add that as an answer rather than a comment?  If not I will, but credit goes to you for the answer so you get first dibs!